# redux-form errors: Element type is invalid: expected a string or function

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to integrate `redux-form (Ver 5.25)` into my react.js based web app, but I run into the following problem with the [simple sync validation redux-form example](http://redux-form.com/5.2.5/#/examples/synchronous-validation?_k=546sgv):

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string 
(for built-in components) or a
 class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

**Code:**

```
<Field name="username" component = {username =>
  <div>
    <input type="text" {...username} placeholder="Username"/>
    {username.touched && username.error && <span>{username.error}</span>}
  </div>
}/>
```

In the custom form component (`UserRegistrationForm`), I have the following code:

```
export default reduxForm({
    form: 'registrationForm',
    fields,
    validate,
})(UserRegistrationForm);
```

And in my root reducers, I mounted redux-form reducer to *form*:

```
form: formReducer,  // redux-form mounted at 'form'
```

So I was wondering what caused the error with the example code above. I guess the **component** part in *Field* is causing it, but I've no idea how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
An appropriate example for using the `Field` [component is here with material-ui](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.7/examples/material-ui/), which I am trying to do something similar to

Comment: Where is `<Field>` component declared?

Comment: There's an import for it: `import { Field } from 'redux-form';`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do

```
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
```

Doesn't seem like that is exported from that package. That's why you're getting that exception, as Field is undefined. I'm not sure what it is you're trying to do with redux-form, I don't see anything like what you're doing in the tutorial you linked to.

Comment: thanks, but there's this example using `Field` component: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.7/examples/material-ui/

Comment: That example is for the 6.0.0 version though, not the 5.25 version. 6.0.0 has Field, but it's new for that and it's still in alpha: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases

Comment: Yes, you are mixing syntax between v5 and v6.

Comment: i'm on 8.2.0 and getting this same error when using Field.